# Tkinter Button call a different class function when right clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple game (minesweeper) that requires a player to right click over spots with bombs, while left clicking to clear spots.

I am using buttons as the tiles that can be clicked on, calling one function, but I need a way to determine if a player clicked using the right click, which would call another function to show a flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `bind` method of `Button` and bind a different function to each mouse button.

```
def left(event):
    print('clicked left')

def right(event):
    print('clicked right')


root = tkinter.Tk()

button = tkinter.Button(root, text='click me')
button.pack()
button.bind('<Button-1>', left)
button.bind('<Button-3>', right)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I already had a function for right click, so I was wondering if bind would work. Testing it out now.

Comment: You can call whatever code/function you want inside the right(event) method.